# Can you create relocatable installations (across machines) with cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'd like to build third_party libraries from source and have importable cmake targets for the pre-built libraries that can be shared with the project (relocatable).

The libraries I'm building come in a few flavors:

- Modern cmake, which can export targets
- Old cmake, which do NOT export targets, but may have pkgconf
- Autoconf / regular makefiles which often have pkgconf outputs
- Small 1-offs with no build files.

There may be some dependencies between the libraries, and a few system dependencies for example:

- LibA depends on LibB
- LibB depends on some libraries found on the system: sysLibXX, sysLibYY

## Question

How can I package the pre-built libraries so that cmake targets and prebuilt libs can be shared and imported to build my project on other machines?

#### Problems

- Using cmake to "install" to a path that can be shared with the project, inherently produces non-relocatable dependencies. For example if math lib `libm` is found by cmake, it's written as an absolute path in the generated exported target produced by cmake `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so`. This doesn't work on others machine with different paths for system libraries.

  - Can I somehow tell cmake to keep library references relocatable in exported targets? (Like: `-lm`)
- Not all packages export cmake files, or even if they do, they may do it incorrectly.

  - Should I be hand-editing or writing from scratch XXConfig.cmake scripts to just make them relocatable?

#### helpful insights

It would be helpful to describe the process to get from source in the various situations above to the redistributable script leveraging any information I can such as pkgconf or automatically generated export targets.

For example:

With vanilla build scripts I can do:

```
./configure --prefix="`pwd`/temp"
make
make install
```

And then maybe I can fixup the pkgconf scripts by hand to remove absolute paths and use a cmake feature to read the pkgconf in a custom XXConfig.cmake??

It'd be really helpful to know if anyone has tried something like this and have some insight into how maintainable it is.

Comment: Hmm, I don't quite understand the question post. Do you want to distribute your project along with all 3d-party libraries, or do you want to allow user to have some 3d-party libraries already installed (by other means), and force your project to use those pre-installed libraries? If you want to discribute all-in-one, do you want `find_package(A)` to work on the user's machine? Or just `find_package(your_project)` should work?

Comment: By `A` I meant a third-party library, which you *distribute with your package*. Since you don't distribute `rt` library (you only *use* it), it is out of scope. So, you main intention is that `find_package(<your_project>)` should work. (Yes, by "your project" I mean things under `app/src`), am I correctly understand you? Or under `app/src` you have just an application, which just should work when run?

Comment: Well. I guess, `find_package(<your_project>)` intended to search 3d-party libraries shipped with your project. (Otherwise, 3d-party libraries would be unrelated to your problem). Such search is normally performed with `find_dependency(A)`. For make this call work, you should install **working** `AConfig.cmake` file. Is it your problem, which you cannot solve?

Comment: Hm, so my understanding wasn't quite right. (`find_package` implies (usually!) that the project XXX is installed, but it may freely use `FindXXX.cmake` instead of `XXXConfig.cmake`). You want to build the project (on your machine?), pack(install) it, and distribute to the other machine, so it will work. Which step is problematic for you? Building the project? Or making the project working on other machine in other environment? If the latter, how environment on other machine is differ from yours?

Comment: "I want to distribute prebuilt versions of the libraries" - This would be sufficient to ask, why you note about your project? It uses libraries via `find_package`? - But any other project will do so. In your question you describe your project's layout, but it is completely unrelated when you distribute a library, which can be used by any projects. And that confused me. Or do you want to support `find_package(all-libs)` which detects all libraries needed for your project?

Comment: Please, be **more specific** with your problems. Is it sufficient to distribute libraries one by one (this would be easier approach), or it is requirement to combine all libraries into one package? If the latter - do you have any problems when combine several libraries into one package. If the former - take one library (e.g. which is built with old cmake; or one which is built with autoconf) and describe what exactly don't work with it.

Comment: You doesn't get any answer, so you may freely rewrite given question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173505/discussion-between-johnb003-and-tsyvarev).

Answer (score 1):

It turns out cmake is able to make relocatable packages, and the problem is mainly with the various 3rd party libraries following anti-patterns.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#creating-relocatable-packages

I have decided to build all of my 3rd party packages like this:

- Libraries that are trusted can install straight to the relocatable installation folder.
- Libraries that aren't write to a temporary location and are scrubbed to automate converting full link paths to just -lLib declarations.

That script looks like this:

```
for FILE in ${CMAKE_FILES}; do
  # Find any paths that begin with "/usr/" and end with "/lib<something>.so"
  # And replace them with -l<something>
  # [^;] is used instead of .*, because ; delimites paths, and there's only greedy regex here.
  sed 's@/usr/[^;]*/lib\([^;]*\)\.so@-l\1@g' "${FILE}" > "${SCRUBBED_CMAKE_PATH}/${FILE#${TEMP_CMAKE_PATH}}"
  echo -e "Scrubbing ${FILE#${TEMP_CMAKE_PATH}}..."
  set +e  # disable error checking for a moment, because diff returns non-0 error codes intentionally
  diff "${FILE}" "${SCRUBBED_CMAKE_PATH}/${FILE#${TEMP_CMAKE_PATH}}"
  set -e  # re-enable error checking
done
```

This is really not portable, and it's really annoying to deal with, so I tend to try to hack the 3rd party CMakeScripts.txt first if I can to fix the non-relocatable issues. ie.
https://github.com/leethomason/tinyxml2/pull/681